# How to prove existence of solutions to the system of Diophantine linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let say that we have a linear system $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m,n}$, $m \neq n$, $\mathbf{A}$ is a full row rank matrix: $rank(\mathbf{A}) = m$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{N}_0^m$. Also all distinct values $a_{i,j} \in \mathbf{A}$ are coprimes. Are there any conditions to check if we can ensure any solution? Could you kindly recommend me some references?

Comment: I've seen a promising comment on mathoverflow - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101536/is-there-a-solution-to-system-of-linear-diophantine-equations written by @WillSawin Could somebody provide some more information to what he wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to give a prove for a subset of the problem thanks to the theorem [1] (page 51):

> Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m,n}$ be a rational matrix of *full row rank*,
>   $rank(\mathbf{A}) = m$, with m rows, and let $\mathbf{b}$ be a
>   rational column m-vector. Then $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}$ has an
>   integral solution $\mathbf{x}$, if and only if each $m \times m$ minor
>   of the matrix $[\mathbf{Ab}]$ is an integral multiple of the
>   *greatest common divisor* of the $m \times m$ minors of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

[1] Theory of linear and integer programming, Alexander Schrijver, 1998